# MLKit header MLKitCommon.h not found

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, google-mlkit

I'm creating react native library using [react native bob builder](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) for scanning images using [Google Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios).

I added pod dependency `pod 'GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning'` in the `.pod` file,

````
 # Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'IosScannerExample' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    #:hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    #:fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
     :hermes_enabled => false,
     :fabric_enabled => false,
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning'

  
  target 'ScannerExampleTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

All google library dependency installed properly in my code.

[image]

Now I importing MLKit framework adding in my class,

```
#import "ScannerViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>

#import <GoogleMLKit/MLKit.h>

@interface ScannerViewController ()

@end
```

When i trying to build my application I getting compliler error from MKKit.h file as below,
[image]

I tried to check all thing required of binding lib's in XCode settings, all settings are correct. Still i'm not able to find out why this error coming from pod framework despite that `MLKitCommon` framework inside the pod.

System Mac OS - 13.5 Ventura, Apple M2

XCode - 14.3.1